# What is wrong with this $.post ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm posting a form vi jQuery's $.post and this is my code:

```
function onSuccess() {
    // Do something onSuccess
    alert('yep');
}

$('#createUserForm').submit( function(){
    $.post("test.php", $(this).serialize(), onSuccess()) 
});
```

How come the browser alerts "yep" and then reloads the page?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For one thing:

```
$.post("test.php", $(this).serialize(), onSuccess); //<--remove the ()
```

Second, disable the default action:

```
$('#createUserForm').submit( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("test.php", $(this).serialize(), onSuccess);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You don't need both `e.preventDefault();` and `return false;`.

Comment: @Rocket ehh better safe than sorry ^_^ (just in case you forget one or the other)